# how can I set db2 CURRENT_TIMEZONE?

Tags: timezone, db2, system

System timezone and DB2 timezones are not matching.
Current system timezone is -5000 and db2 gives me back -40000 with the following query
**select CURRENT_TIMEZONE from SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1**

how and where can I set this value?

Comment: What do you mean by "_Current system timezone is -5000_"? What is _system_ in this case? DB2 will use the timezone setting on the database server.

Comment: It's Suse, I found that database will not automatically update after system time zone is changed, the db2 instance needs to be restarted.

Comment: Note:  Using SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1 in order to use a SELECT most expressions is unnecessary.  You can use a [VALUES statement](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v10r1/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc%2Fdoc%2Fr0001024.html) instead.  `VALUES CURRENT_TIMEZONE`

Comment: @WarrenT Your assertion is incorrect. Have you ever looked at the definition of SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1?  `create view sysibm.sysdummy1 (ibmreqd) as values (char('Y'))`

Comment: @IanBjorhovde are you trying to say that `values current_timezone` does not work on your DB2 server? I don't think I understand your point. My point was that the values statement (see link above) can be used in most cases that I have seen where someone is querying SYSDUMMY1 merely because the expression they want evaluated is not in any of their tables. With the VALUES statement expression results can be returned without having to use any dummy table.

Comment: @WarrenT I was pointing out the fact that because `SYSDUMMY1` is in itself a simple `VALUES` statement, there is literally no difference between issuing `select current_timezone from sysibm.sysdummy1` and `values current_timezone` – they will have the *exact same* explain plan.  In fact, the optimizer rewrites `values current_timezone` as `select current timezone from (values 1) as q1`

Comment: @IanBjorhovde Yes, we agree they are the same.  Therefore, why would anyone ever type out `select expr from sysibm.sysdummy1` when you could use `values expr`?  The syntax is simpler, more quickly read, more quickly understood.  And who wants pointless code cluttering things up?

Comment: @IanBjorhovde  Simple, clear code benefits software quality.

Comment: @IanBjorhovde BTW, a follow-up note:  I finally looked at the definition of SYSDUMMY1.  (about time, eh?)  On DB2 for i 7.1, the definition is:  `CREATE TABLE SYSIBM/SYSDUMMY1 ( IBMREQD VARCHAR(1) CCSID 37 DEFAULT NULL );`.  Just thought you might like to know that it varies by platform.

Answer (score 0):

I hope  it could help   SELECT DBNAME, TSNAME, DSNUM, ICTYPE, TIMESTAMP - CURRENT TIMEZONE
          FROM SYSIBM.SYSCOPY;

Answer (score 0):

I've found a way, I had to restart the database instance.
db2 force application all
db2stop
db2start